# Issue in ajax refreshing without reloading

Tags: ajax

I have this code here which I use in order to refresh a page every 30 seconds.

My problem is, the page that loads inside the other page appears very late.

How can I customize this function in order to make it appear in the page at the first moment it loads, and for it to refresh in each 30 seconds?

```
function()
{
$('#lista').show().load('pagination.php');}, 30000);
```

I mean, I have the lista.php page, in which I load the pagination.php page.
When I go to lista.php the pagination.php should appear immediately.
But it doesn't.
How should i modify it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is incomplete. I assume it looks like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#lista').show().load('pagination.php');
}, 30000);
```

You don't have to call show() each time. Element #lista is visible, right?
 For it to execute at startup:

```
function LoadContent()
{
    $('#lista').load('pagination.php');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadContent(); //load contentent when page loads
    setInterval('LoadContent()',30000); //schedule refresh
});
```

Comment: uhmm, no, in fact that's the code i'm using.. you think i should replace it with this?

Comment: Well, no, this doesn't reload the page..
it shows the content right away though

Comment: Could you please please, take a look at this?
Thanks!

Comment: I thought that is what you needed. This code loads pagination.php into #lista element when the page it shows in 30 secunds intervals. Could you explain what more do you need?

Comment: Yes, that's what i needed, but the issue is it is not reloading the lista div every 30 seconds.. it's not working i mean...

Comment: I'm sorry, i do have a urgency with this... :S
i'm posting a new question with your proposed code..
Thanks..

Comment: There was misteke - should be 'setInterval' instead 'setTimeout'. I corrected the answer.